# Why Is My Object's Value Becoming None Every Time I Use The + Operator?

Tags: python

I am relatively new to Python. I implemented a trie data structure, and now I am testing it. However, for some reason my object becomes `None` every time I use the '+' operator.

```
class Trie:
    class Node:
        def __init__(self):
            self.count = 0
            self.children = [None] * 26

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = self.Node()

    def __add__(self, string):
        curr = self.root

        for i in range(len(string)):
            index = ord(string[i]) - ord('a')

            if curr.children[index] is None:
                curr.children[index] = self.Node()

            curr = curr.children[index]

        curr.count = curr.count + 1

    def __contains__(self, string):
        curr = self.root

        for i in range(len(string)):
            index = ord(string[i]) - ord('a')

            if curr.children[index] is None:
                return False

            curr = curr.children[index]

        return curr.count > 0
```

My testing class looks like this:

```
import random
import string

from src.main.python.datastructures.trees.trie.trie import Trie


def generate_random_string():
    return ''.join([random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase) for _ in range(32)])


def test_trie():
    for i in range(100):
        random_string_list = []
        t = Trie()

        for j in range(100):
            random_string = generate_random_string()
            random_string_list.append(random_string)
            t += random_string # After this line, t becomes None

        for random_string in random_string_list:
            assert random_string in t

            next_random_string = generate_random_string()

            if random_string_list not in next_random_string:
                assert next_random_string not in t
```

As stated in the comments of the code, when I was debugging the code, `t` becomes `None`, so I get a type error which looks something like `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for None and str`.

Comment: For `+=` you should really be implementing the [`__iadd__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iadd__) function in your object (this was found very quickly with a very simple search).

Comment: You also don't return anything from `__add__`, which is the root cause (modifying in place is a bad idea).  The default `__iadd__` will probably work if you return.

Comment: Oh thanks, I got it. I just added a `return self` at the end.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude - Its not strictly necessary, `+=` will fall back to `__add__` if `__iadd__` isn't there. https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iadd__

Comment: If you modify `self` in place, why assign back to itself? Basically what you have is a situation where `x + y` will modify `x`, which isn't how the `+` operator should work. It should create a *new* object, update the new object, and return it.